# Squid3 a lot of access.log

Tags: proxy, squid

Well, i'm new in Squid3 and i configured only one machine to use this proxy, just for test. But the access.log don't stop to grown, like someone is using right now, but i know that only machine should use it, is turn off right now.

This is a peace of my access.log copy right now:

```
1485280575.486    589 122.227.189.207 TCP_MISS/200 619 GET http://1212.ip138.com/ic.asp - HIER_DIRECT/183.238.101.232 text/html
1485280575.499    175 74.91.26.210 TCP_MISS/403 1260 GET http://220.243.224.56/pl3.live.panda.tv/live_panda/8a36354c4b174f4bf928cef8716af13.flv? - HIER_DIRECT/220.243.224.56 text/html
1485280575.502    498 153.92.0.2 TCP_MISS/200 936 CONNECT www.google.co.jp:80 - HIER_DIRECT/216.58.217.67 -
1485280575.503     77 153.92.0.2 TCP_MISS/200 4118 CONNECT ipv4.google.com:80 - HIER_DIRECT/172.217.2.14 -
1485280575.509    398 153.92.0.2 TCP_MISS/200 1058 CONNECT www.google.co.jp:80 - HIER_DIRECT/216.58.217.67 -
1485280575.509     78 153.92.0.2 TCP_MISS/200 4283 CONNECT ipv4.google.com:80 - HIER_DIRECT/172.217.2.14 -
1485280575.513     77 204.12.222.174 TCP_MISS/403 1250 GET http://220.243.199.44/pl3.live.panda.tv/live_panda/1eb9c24f203a5aacadfc432719426fb.flv? - HIER_DIRECT/220.243.199.44 text/html
1485280575.513    195 192.187.103.91 TCP_MISS/403 1256 GET http://220.243.236.195/pl3.live.panda.tv/live_panda/db064c04950c9a56248d7fddcbfb066.flv? - HIER_DIRECT/220.243.236.195 text/html
1485280575.528      0 120.194.46.138 TCP_MISS_ABORTED/000 0 GET http://120.77.54.33:808/verifycode.php - HIER_DIRECT/120.77.54.33
```

Do you guys think someone is using my proxy server without my permission ? THe log is almost 1GB right now and growing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't set up access control and have it available over the internet, you implicitly gave everyone permission to use it. And yes, it's getting used because there are scanners searching for such open proxies.

Turn it off until you setup authentication and encryption.

Comment: I imagine that someone is using over internet. How can i allow only one IP ?

Comment: You will need to read up on squid and ACL's.  There are a myriad of examples on the web for how to lock down squid to particular IP's, hosts, networks, users, etc.

Answer (score 0):

By default, squid does not grant access to any IP. The access log shows the information you need to know. The access log fields are as follow:

1. Date/time in seconds (epoch time).
2. Response time.
3. Client source IP address.
4. Request status.
5. etc...

If you can recognize these IPs, it is OK. Otherwise, you need to review your config. You can look for `acl` and `http_access` config parameters. You need to pay attention to the order to `http_access` statements as it matters.